# How to check my own voicemail Greeting on iphone?

Tags: iphone, applications, call, voicemail

I want to listen to my voicemail greeting on my iphone. I would think that there would be an option somewhere in my voicemail section of the phone app, but when I go there and I am forced to "call my voicemail" I never get an option to listen to it, only to change it. I am afraid it I go to change it that it will delete it bc the system is badly designed.

Comment: This will be entirely provider-dependant.

Comment: @Tetsujin virgin canada

Comment: If I go to Phone -> Voicemail, I have a "Salution" option on top left (above the "Voicemail" title) from which I can listen to my message. Don't you have something similar?

Comment: @nohillside no, the page only has Voicemail title on top left and then a small button at center of screen "call voicemail"

Comment: Ok, this looks like you don't have Visual Voicemal activated. Then, as @tetsujin said, this is provider-dependant.

Comment: @nohillside what does that mean in terms of solving my problem? I've tried calling myself through internet phones but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Call yourself from any other phone maybe? And contact Virgin Canada to get Visual Voicemail enabled, it makes quite some difference especially if a lot of calls go to voicemail.

Comment: Visual Voicemail doesn't let me listen to the greeting, it's set to 'default' with no 'play' button. The only way is to call myself from my phone, and it plays the greeting. If it goes straight to voicemail management, then you'll just have to use a different phone to call yourself.